# global Variables not getting updated

Tags: python

```
answer_B = ["B", "b"]
answer_C = ["C", "c"]
def tool1():
  global tool
  tool = 1
def ore1():
  global ore
  ore = 1
def cave():
  ore = 0
  tool = 0
  while True:
    print("\nYou walk inside the clocktower, looking all around and you see 3 rooms. \n Room A fulled with ORE \n Room B which has a Smelter \n Room C walled off with rocks")
    choice3 = input(">>")
    if choice3 in answer_A:
      print("You grab the ore and walk observe the rooms \n +1 ore")
      ore1()
      print(ore)
    elif choice3 in answer_B:
      if ore == 1:
        print("You use the ore and smelt it into iron chunks, and you craft an iron pickaxe \n + Iron Tool")
        tool1()
        print(tool)
      elif ore == 0:
        print("You walk inside, and observe the smelter with coal inside, Maybe you can smelt some sort of ore and make an tool?")
    elif choice3 in answer_C:
      if tool == 0 and ore == 0:
        print("You observe thde wall walled off with rocks, Maybe you could smelt ore and make a tool?")
      elif tool == 0 and ore == 1:
        print("You have the ore, You need to make it into a tool? Maybe the smelter room could help")
      elif tool == 1:
        print("You use the tool and break the wall")
         
    if tool1() == 1:
      print("You Did It!")
      break
cave()
```

Why is the ore not getting updated to 1 when you do Choice A? I Made it a global variable but I'm don't know what else I could do
(I'm new to python, sorry if its a dumb question)

Comment: you made `ore` global in `ore1()` function only.
Also a minor suggestion, you should use meaningfull variable/ fucntion names.

Comment: Exactly, the variables aren't place in the global namespace, means at the beginning of your script. Good luck :)

Comment: also you code have some errors like `name 'answer_A' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 `ore` variables in your code. One is local inside the `cave()` function and another one is global. When you are calling the `ore1()` function, the global variable is getting updated to 1 as expected but the `ore` variable that you are printing in the next line is the local `ore` variable. To fix this, you can declare the `ore` variable global at the start of the `cave()` function too just like you did in the 'ore1()' function

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing all this:

1. Declare tool and ore at the beginning itself

`tool = 0`
    `ore = 0`

2. Wherever you wrote `tool1()`, replace it with `tool = 1` and `ore1()` with `ore = 1`